# Customise vega-lite Line Graph Axis Labels

Tags: vega-lite

What I want to do is really simple, but I just can't seem to get it right. I have a feeling I'm going to be embarrassed by the answer!

I have a line graph with "attempt" along the x-axis and "grade" along the y-axis, with grade being a number between 0 and 100. I simply want to change the y-axis so that, instead of seeing the raw number, a grade is show, say with 0 - 20 representing "E", 20-40 being "D" etc up to "A" (80-100). How can I do that? I don't want to use discrete values because I want to visually show where within a grade boundary a grade falls. I'm not sure whether I yet want to simply display the grade bands on the line or put them in the middle of their ticks, but just getting somewhere with this would help a lot!

Here is what I've been working with in the vega-lite editor:

```
    {
      "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.json",
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {
            "attempt": 1,
            "score": 30
          },
          {
            "attempt": 2,
            "score": 60
          },
          {
            "attempt": 3,
            "score": 75
          },
          {
            "attempt": 4,
            "score": 58
          },
          {
            "attempt": 5,
            "score": 67
          }
        ]
      },
      "mark": {
        "type": "line",
        "color": "#22bc9a",
        "point": {
          "filled": false
        }
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "attempt",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {
            "grid": false,
            "tickCount": 5,
            "title": "Attempt"
          }
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "score",
          "scale": {"domain": [0, 100]},
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {
            "tickCount": 5,
            "title": "Grade"
          }
        },
        "opacity": {"value": 0.3}
      },
      "config": {
        "autosize": "fit",
        "axis": {
          "labelColor": "#bebec8",
          "tickColor": "#bebec8",
          "titleColor": "black",
          "titleFontWeight": "normal",
          "titleFontSize": 11,
          "labelFont": "Helvetica",
          "titleFont": "Helvetica",
          "gridOpacity": 0.4,
          "gridWidth": 1.5,
          "domain": false
        },
        "view": {
          "strokeWidth": 0
        }
      }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this: I add a dataframe with the grade category, and use this to layer some text. I remove the labels of the axis and so the text acts as if it were the labels of the axis.

The chart looks like this, and [here is a link to the editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-34wVsQnoMRqGAA9A-HqhFAA6VB3RgXdZv5CwB8LyIYJnw8RRsktJJnxEN8ACsagQAkVSMWF6EFAY7G3Fw3CSTxvC0QJGygD4vngchckzSBpWsSVmhnEEqTmBIAFFd1wOsiP2T5x2aSjqNlUR6L2RjbAAETY-xnk4kieIom1+No-IhOKESElZCSpCkm0ZLIrA5JBBTyAAdmU6pVKgAAhDSOO07jdN4+SZVogBOUzeHMyAy2siRjwkTDdUFSc9E43NgOrPTKJ7NQmjEA1CJtUL80dMAACZIrgaLyAANjYOKzBCyswuSkR0t7Yz03dLSQUS8KwBYUrMrTco8uChLCqS7kGqaLKjP3XBl38EBJCAA):
[image: chart_with_grades_for_axis]

Schema (Note that I did it with Python's Altair, so it may not be canonical Vega-lite, and I did not use your settings either, sorry about that):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.6.0.json",
  "config": {
    "view": {
      "height": 300,
      "width": 400
    }
  },
  "datasets": {
    "data-1acee7c5d817865a529b53e022474ce8": [
      {
        "label": "E",
        "x_min": 1,
        "y_med": 10
      },
      {
        "label": "D",
        "x_min": 1,
        "y_med": 30
      },
      {
        "label": "C",
        "x_min": 1,
        "y_med": 50
      },
      {
        "label": "B",
        "x_min": 1,
        "y_med": 70
      },
      {
        "label": "A",
        "x_min": 1,
        "y_med": 90
      }
    ],
    "data-8e6359ea3034b8410708361bb10fafd5": [
      {
        "attempt": 1,
        "score": 30
      },
      {
        "attempt": 2,
        "score": 60
      },
      {
        "attempt": 3,
        "score": 75
      },
      {
        "attempt": 4,
        "score": 58
      },
      {
        "attempt": 5,
        "score": 67
      }
    ]
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "data": {
        "name": "data-1acee7c5d817865a529b53e022474ce8"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "field": "label",
          "type": "ordinal"
        },
        "x": {
          "field": "x_min",
          "scale": {
            "zero": false
          },
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "y": {
          "axis": {
            "labels": false,
            "tickCount": 5,
            "ticks": false
          },
          "field": "y_med",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      },
      "mark": {
        "dx": -15,
        "dy": 8,
        "size": 15,
        "type": "text"
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "name": "data-8e6359ea3034b8410708361bb10fafd5"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "axis": {
            "tickCount": 5
          },
          "field": "attempt",
          "title": "Attempt",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "score",
          "scale": {
            "domain": [
              0,
              100
            ]
          },
          "title": "Grade",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      },
      "mark": {
        "point": true,
        "type": "line"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Using a slighly modified dataframe for the categories (with `x_max`, `y_min` and `y_max` added), you can add another layer with colored rectangles, that can help read the values:
[image: chart_with_grade_axis_and_color_bands]

Here is a [link to the editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAmOgDY6ABjoArWNwB2kADTgo8TQDNG1bGFAQIkCo2QB3MxctWUJ-GYDMixbudW7jAAmLGYALN56EAC+elG+UIHoeOiwyHiwjpEJSaIAjOjwyMgA7PAArIEAHLnFlXJl6GXSAJzsZR7IitLSocWhhZVmANpZEE5+UGLo7MhiZpAAojqjlpAAHgD6qIxaOLnxE5AAnlvIgWa5iitxK+N+kFMzcziQACLLE1ab27tg+ytWE6oM6eK4TG4TO7OB7TWbzADCH0+6y2OwuB3uQJBODKYL8EL8UNWjzhLwAQkjDt80XsMdCseccMU8c4Cc4iVYSc8oABBSn3am-f6fKAMszNFmWGLOAC6GMgiWSIg8zUMhnYiWkbUCZUMyGackCyEqoUCzWQXkqZukijVw1uAMmsO5i350O+6DWZjKdNWgvRjuOW09ZhtvsBp0Zfx8gaBNLAkuivo5Tqe83e4agHq9OMzKJ+AZFQYwObA4TzYpwXgrqN+NuuycDXIRbr9wdLPsD-tpsfbZjkMaLlbAuJrBZw4QbDqLzfJra+fdzXdrheRQJDOEqg7XkbMzLH8YHU8hTed8z5eez3svK57Q8X0e3h2HEoPvy31yycqyCpyIkqyByB4ZTmugXgeKE7AmpczKVB4ci5Ow7CXIY6CGDq9onkWSR4GghB4KuhwINwABOyCgsehKBjheEETg0h5sRZH9omYBspYKaQDRqD4Z4jEGMxTJlJR7LUQQtFhPxpHkTilQiRxYm4TxdEjlJglgHIxSfrKsTxDCRzICRmEKYciqYDgnEaOgwLzGZyqquqmrarq+qGsaprmpa1q2oYkDyVYyAaAYgQ7KYFmBgYYikZkIpWMYsxRjCaaZlYCDoGIMnmI60L8GgmWQNQZGBewYisOR2VsSlUB4EchD5aRIVWXMjrse6MWxZA8ViIl-pVZAaUZe1sVQAAXoZ3BmKhYipBVrX3HgzCDS8PLicp86rDVdXzAAjqw6AaAtyQLVQfkinNXzSENyJdT1fZ9Zt+W7fth1JIwJ0tRWV2HJ6jAZDgGisGIYh9Td8xxlo921Y9e0Hcwr3vWdFaXeFw2dbY3Vg3dFWQA9O0wy9x3lWd-lQBgJEANbzGR8AEVk7FEr+yRfasVk2S8dn5IUJTlFUNR1A0TStO0nTdL0-TGqd+K+pAgXBaFzNWLhawqSmcXo4lzaQ1tLwNTs6WS+Cl4K6soMvL12MDZlqurGNJETTgU0zcN50bVDePPXDhMG1LsbG1YP1-Vlw2cs6geO8gVWK4w8Dk-C3CsAd14VVHMdh+lTuxS7asJZjwLnFr0Me0db1E580o+4cZOUyjyKBKWIi5J2RaBEcZiVIxjBjRcTfIrjLxK7T4J0xiDNmcbkCs-ldkAUBIHIGBigQVBoQwYocEIUhKFoRhJMy0F3CNWFQfIqW1tcWsv1+xt0ex-Hic4rNIPq-M3G8fdi35StSlv9jfdQE9sNi4IzLp9GuRZTZQCYuRPqlsr5WECNwDA8YRjB0sE+YOlxWITBlI-X+H95gAHESLoCNOtRWbsXgAIJiXb2rJd5V3HoQbgOwVJ4BImVPMf8Hg7FLnQvhYAcFRCAA)

And here is the schema

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.6.0.json",
  "config": {
    "view": {
      "height": 300,
      "width": 400
    }
  },
  "datasets": {
    "data-1acee7c5d817865a529b53e022474ce8": [
      {
        "label": "E",
        "x_min": 1,
        "y_med": 10
      },
      {
        "label": "D",
        "x_min": 1,
        "y_med": 30
      },
      {
        "label": "C",
        "x_min": 1,
        "y_med": 50
      },
      {
        "label": "B",
        "x_min": 1,
        "y_med": 70
      },
      {
        "label": "A",
        "x_min": 1,
        "y_med": 90
      }
    ],
    "data-39ffbda2b5d5fe96de84d9e308d920ff": [
      {
        "label": "E",
        "x_max": 5,
        "x_min": 1,
        "y_max": 20,
        "y_med": 10,
        "y_min": 0
      },
      {
        "label": "D",
        "x_max": 5,
        "x_min": 1,
        "y_max": 40,
        "y_med": 30,
        "y_min": 20
      },
      {
        "label": "C",
        "x_max": 5,
        "x_min": 1,
        "y_max": 60,
        "y_med": 50,
        "y_min": 40
      },
      {
        "label": "B",
        "x_max": 5,
        "x_min": 1,
        "y_max": 80,
        "y_med": 70,
        "y_min": 60
      },
      {
        "label": "A",
        "x_max": 5,
        "x_min": 1,
        "y_max": 100,
        "y_med": 90,
        "y_min": 80
      }
    ],
    "data-8e6359ea3034b8410708361bb10fafd5": [
      {
        "attempt": 1,
        "score": 30
      },
      {
        "attempt": 2,
        "score": 60
      },
      {
        "attempt": 3,
        "score": 75
      },
      {
        "attempt": 4,
        "score": 58
      },
      {
        "attempt": 5,
        "score": 67
      }
    ]
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "data": {
        "name": "data-39ffbda2b5d5fe96de84d9e308d920ff"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "field": "label",
          "scale": {
            "scheme": "greenblue"
          },
          "type": "ordinal"
        },
        "x": {
          "field": "x_min",
          "scale": {
            "zero": false
          },
          "title": "Attempt",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "x2": {
          "field": "x_max",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "y": {
          "axis": null,
          "field": "y_min",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "y2": {
          "field": "y_max",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      },
      "mark": "rect"
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "name": "data-1acee7c5d817865a529b53e022474ce8"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "field": "label",
          "type": "ordinal"
        },
        "x": {
          "field": "x_min",
          "scale": {
            "zero": false
          },
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "y": {
          "axis": {
            "labels": false,
            "tickCount": 5,
            "ticks": false
          },
          "field": "y_med",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      },
      "mark": {
        "dx": -15,
        "dy": 8,
        "size": 15,
        "type": "text"
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "name": "data-8e6359ea3034b8410708361bb10fafd5"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "axis": {
            "tickCount": 5
          },
          "field": "attempt",
          "title": "Attempt",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "score",
          "scale": {
            "domain": [
              0,
              100
            ]
          },
          "title": "Grade",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      },
      "mark": {
        "point": true,
        "type": "line"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks FlorianGD! I'd never have figured that out!

Answer (score 0):

To get it working, I first had to change the encoding of the x and y axis to be ordinal.  Then I mapped your input data values to letter grades *before* creating the schema:

```
//replace every score value with correct letter grade
values.forEach(datapoint => {
  if(datapoint.score > 90) {
    datapoint.score = "A";
  } else if(datapoint.score > 80) {
    datapoint.score = "B";
  } else if (datapoint.score > 70) {
    //so on...
  }
});
```

Here is a working example in the vega-lite editor:
[Line Chart with Ordinal Values](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABBkEQCQM4GMAWBTAtgQygLjFJALgQA5zYD05AbigOYYB0tAlgUgK4BGDzA9uYlSZqdDAFoANqxTUAzAwBWcXgDsoAGnCQIUACYYCWXKG3aoVDBPYo4OMAG0tpyCeemoBgumIE7ARk03d0ReACcUOygAMSgnNwBfQKCwV2S8T29fXAAmJLSoEPDIgBFYtMS451TkjyJMu1k8msKI3CgAYTLkirTqoNqvNB87ABYm-pbImMrTHuS+twH63ABWccXJttKZ7XidsABdGbmzTFCAazsFnQIAT2JWvCkVCPWdBF4JMMiAYmzszgIACcWDeeGIvGYKiyKX2OgAZswJBIULo7PDLHAUPs9s4TtAUCoProobQrvsoAAPcn5REoCRotoZIa+ME3e6PKBhEkqSwaOHpSnMWzGAU3VgoyIAQTqLK6QVxCTBUFuNJqdIZkUmbLwdwekW5UL5Oo8QpFsLS4oIkraAHFQhhdBEBYq8creMQMAhWKrjOZLNY7AAGBiyV2QfHvVSIsmi-oYdgEXhwZgAL05iNZFIwZrV-QkGE49Pan2+bR+RaLCAAHPz8gRmAhziWvqFfpWUDW6zUG9aUC2y3hOAWm93+r2UVFVAQAOooZi0QiRFRhTASMeLCcoKfQgDKacefgCAqgBaLEh3MKgAAl6TQGwhQSet5fIreJPfG0-8rRQsxdAA8p63p3MGDBjCev7-jO-5sP4DArDiypUMwKAAO55hsBChLw5woDBuhwbgQY4sccR7EAA)

Here is the schema:

```
{
      "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.json",
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {
            "attempt": 1,
            "score": "F"
          },
          {
            "attempt": 2,
            "score": "D"
          },
          {
            "attempt": 3,
            "score": "C"
          },
          {
            "attempt": 4,
            "score": "F"
          },
          {
            "attempt": 5,
            "score": "D"
          }
        ]
      },
      "mark": {
        "type": "line",
        "color": "#22bc9a",
        "point": {
          "filled": false
        }
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "attempt",
          "type": "ordinal",
          "axis": {
            "title": "Attempt"
          }
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "score",
          "type": "ordinal",
          "axis": {
            "title": "Grade"
          }
        },
        "opacity": {"value": 0.3}
      },
      "config": {
        "autosize": "fit",
        "axis": {
          "labelColor": "#bebec8",
          "tickColor": "#bebec8",
          "titleColor": "black",
          "titleFontWeight": "normal",
          "titleFontSize": 11,
          "labelFont": "Helvetica",
          "titleFont": "Helvetica",
          "gridOpacity": 0.4,
          "gridWidth": 1.5
        },
        "view": {
          "strokeWidth": 0
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this isn't quite what I'm looking for. I don't want the graph to lose information by putting all values for a grade together. I want to be able to see where on the scale attempts came, and how far between the grades they are. Basically, I want to plot the numbers 1 to 100 as they are, but modify the scale displayed.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense.  You might try looking into axis formatting in vega - you can get the compiled vega spec and use `encode.labels.update.text` to specify whatever text you want for each tick on the axis. See "Custom Axis Encodings" on the doc page: https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/axes/.  At the bottom of the page it says: "Custom text can be defined using the "text" property for labels. For example, one could define an ordinal scale that serves as a lookup table from axis values to axis label text." That sounds like what you want.